# Unable to upload image from a custom form - getting ERROR - [The file was not uploaded]

Tags: forms, magento2.3.3, image-upload, file-uploader

I am trying to upload a file, but getting error every time - The file was not uploaded

Steps that I am following -

**Html -**

```
<div class="field npwp_attachment" id="npwp-attachment-div">
        <label class="label" for="npwp_attachment">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Attach NPWP – Company')) ?></span>
        </label>
        <div class="control">
            <input name="company[npwp_attachment]" id="npwp_attachment" title="<?php  $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Attach NPWP – Company')) ?>" class="input-file" type="file" >
        </div>
    </div>
```

**In Model -**

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
protected $uploaderFactory;
protected $adapterFactory;
protected $filesystem;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $adapterFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
){
    $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
    $this->adapterFactory = $adapterFactory;
    $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
}
        $uploaderFactory = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'npwp_attachment']);
        $uploaderFactory->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
        $imageAdapter = $this->adapterFactory->create();
        /* start of validated image */
        $uploaderFactory->addValidateCallback('custom_image_upload',
            $imageAdapter,'validateUploadFile');
        $uploaderFactory->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $uploaderFactory->setFilesDispersion(true);
        $mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $destinationPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('custom_image');
        echo $destinationPath;exit;
        $result = $uploaderFactory->save($destinationPath);
        if (!$result) {
            throw new LocalizedException(
                __('File cannot be saved to path: $1', $destinationPath)
            );
        }
```

In model, I have also printed $_FILES and this is the response -

```
Array
(
[company] => Array
    (
        [name] => Array
            (
                [npwp_attachment] => Untitled Diagram.jpg
            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [npwp_attachment] => image/jpeg
            )

        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [npwp_attachment] => /tmp/phpOtC07v
            )

        [error] => Array
            (
                [npwp_attachment] => 0
            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [npwp_attachment] => 153369
            )

    )
```

)

**Findings till now -**

I have figured out that their is some issue with **tmp_name**, this error is coming form -

```
vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php

if (!file_exists($this->_file['tmp_name'])) {
        $code = empty($this->_file['tmp_name']) ? self::TMP_NAME_EMPTY : 0;
        throw new \DomainException('The file was not uploaded.', $code);
    }
```

I have also printed **$this->_file['tmp_name']**, and this is empty.

**I am getting error in this line -**

```
$uploaderFactory = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'npwp_attachment']);
```

Any idea what is the issue and how this can be fixed ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The fileId for the the following line is wrong.

```
$uploaderFactory = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'npwp_attachment']);
```

It needs to match the name attribute on the input field.